# Newsgroup analysis web site

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web application that will analyze a public news group for top posters over a specific period of time?

The more analysis the better!

Note: While it is public, it isn't listed on Google Groups.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of Newsgroups [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/usenet-i/groups-html/), clicking on each one brings up some statistics, but not top posters unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Marc Smith did research into [analyzing and visualizing newsgroup activity](http://www.connectedaction.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/2004-hicss-viegas-and-smith-newsgroup-crowds-and-author-lines.pdf) while he was at Microsoft Research.  I don't think it was a webapp, but it was called "Newsgroup Clouds".  I have no idea how he gathered the data for analysis -- if he was subscribing to the feeds over time, or if he could analyze a new newsgroup on demand.